# USB flash icon on desktop (Kubuntu 16.04)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I plug an USB flash, it is automatically mounted in /media. However, an icon isn't shown on the desktop as with LXDE. Any idea to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no desktop icons possible in Kubuntu.
You could make it showing up in for example the `cairo-dock`.

Homepage:

http://glx-dock.org/

Installation:

for Ubuntu users, you can simply copy/paste these 3 lines into a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then if Cairo-Dock is already installed:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

else:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins
```